# Adding a where clause to DB:raw statement in Laravel to return count of comments where deleted_at is null

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to return the count of comments on posts. Comments are softDeleted which is why I'm checking deleted_at = null. Below is the code I have:

```
$posts = Post::select(
   ...
   DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT post_comments.id) as comment_count'),
   ...
)->where('post_comments.deleted_at', '=', null)
```

With the above code the correct number of comments are returned, but if a post has a comment that has been deleted, then that post is excluded from the select, and therefore doesn't show in the list of posts that are returned, if even 1 comment has been deleted on the post.

I've tried to modify it to this, getting rid of the where clause after the select:

```
$posts = Post::select(
   ...
   DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT post_comments.id WHERE post_comments.deleted_at IS NULL) as comment_count'),
   ...
)
```

This contains a SQL error that I haven't been able to figure out. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use eloquent relationship for post_comments; after that you can do this:

```
$comment = Post::withCount('post_comments')->get();
```